# How to intergrate @JsonView and HATEOAS in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where I need to have JsonViews which can be done as shown below:

```
@JsonView(Institution.InstitutionView.class)
@GetMapping
Page<Institution> getInstitutions( 
   @PageableDefault(sort = "institutionName") Pageable pageable) {
      return institutionService.fetchSortedInstitutions(pageable);
}
```

However, the current implementation is using paged resources like this:

```
@GetMapping 
PagedResources<InstitutionResource> getInstitutions(
   @PageableDefault(sort = "institutionName") Pageable pageable,
   PagedResourcesAssembler<Institution> pagedResourcesAssembler){
     return pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(
        this.institutionService.fetchSortedInstitutions(pageable), 
        new InstitutionResourceAssembler());
}
```

how can I have the two implementations together?
Basically how to use @JsonViews and HATEOAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it's impossible, because [following PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/pull/387) is still open.
You have to wait until it would be resolved.

---

Edited:

You could also use Jackson Mixins for that. Here is my example for wrapping some object with HATEOAS Resource class:

```
public abstract class ResourceMixin {
    @JsonView(CustomView.class)
    public abstract List<Link> getLinks();

    @JsonView(CustomView.class)
    public abstract Link getLink(String rel);

    @JsonView(CustomView.class)
    public abstract Object getContent();
}
```

You have to register such mixin somewhere. I have used Spring Boot for that:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder(){
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.mixIn(Resource.class, ResourceMixin.class);
    return builder;
}
```